# Passing string got from fgets to a function and use it inside

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
void main()
{
  // Ask user for input file name
  char file_name[100]; 
  printf("File Name?: \n");
  fgets(file_name, 100, stdin);
  printf("Your input: %s", file_name);  
  processFile(file_name);
}
```

Which is used to get the value of the input file that needs to be read.  Then in the processFile function, I do the following:

```
void processFile(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *in = fopen(file_name,"r");
}
```

But I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped).  I fail to see why.

Thanks

Comment: On what line?  Did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: Yes. Exactly on the only line that is found in ProcessFile.

Comment: Have you considered trimming the newline off the filename you just entered?

Comment: what do you mean trimming?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Try with

```
 scanf("%s", file_name);
```

Comment: -1 that makes for a possible buffer overflow.  You should use `"%99s"` instead.  It also disallows filenames with spaces, which might be good or bad.

Comment: Instead of puting -1, give  us your solution.